# Smooth color transition algorithm

Tags: c++, colors

I am looking for a general algorithm to smoothly transition between two colors.

For example, this image is taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Black-body-in-mireds-reversed.png) and shows a transition from orange to blue.

[image]

When I try to do the same using my code (C++), first idea that came to mind is using the HSV color space, but the annoying in-between colors show-up.

[image]

What is the good way to achieve this ? Seems to be related to diminution of contrast or maybe use a different color space ?

Comment: Note that this particular transition from orange to blue is a very specific case, and not the application of a general algorithm,. In particular, this is the [Planckian Locus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planckian_locus) - the visible color of a blackbody emitter as it heats up from a dull red glow to sizzling hot.

Comment: Have you tried linear interpolation in YUV color space instead of HSV?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have done tons of these in the past.  The smoothing can be performed many different ways, but the way they are probably doing here is a simple linear approach.  This is to say that for each R, G, and B component, they simply figure out the "y = m*x + b" equation that connects the two points, and use that to figure out the components in between.

```
m[RED]   = (ColorRight[RED]   - ColorLeft[RED])   / PixelsWidthAttemptingToFillIn
m[GREEN] = (ColorRight[GREEN] - ColorLeft[GREEN]) / PixelsWidthAttemptingToFillIn
m[BLUE]  = (ColorRight[BLUE]  - ColorLeft[BLUE])  / PixelsWidthAttemptingToFillIn

b[RED]   = ColorLeft[RED]
b[GREEN] = ColorLeft[GREEN]
b[BLUE]  = ColorLeft[BLUE]
```

Any new color in between is now:

```
NewCol[pixelXFromLeft][RED]   = m[RED]   * pixelXFromLeft + ColorLeft[RED]    
NewCol[pixelXFromLeft][GREEN] = m[GREEN] * pixelXFromLeft + ColorLeft[GREEN]
NewCol[pixelXFromLeft][BLUE]  = m[BLUE]  * pixelXFromLeft + ColorLeft[BLUE]
```

There are many mathematical ways to create a transition, what we really want to do is understand what transition you really want to see.  If you want to see the exact transition from the above image, it is worth looking at the color values of that image.  I wrote a program way back in time to look at such images and output there values graphically.  Here is the output of my program for the above pseudocolor scale.

[image]

Based upon looking at the graph, it IS more complex than a linear as I stated above.  The blue component looks mostly linear, the red could be emulated to linear, the green however looks to have a more rounded shape.  We could perform mathematical analysis of the green to better understand its mathematical function, and use that instead.  You may find that a linear interpolation with an increasing slope between 0 and ~70 pixels with a linear decreasing slope after pixel 70 is good enough.

If you look at the bottom of the screen, this program gives some statistical measures of each color component, such as min, max, and average, as well as how many pixels wide the image read was.

Comment: Thanks, seems I complicated things when the obvious was what was needed!

Comment: @trumpetlicks : Just a very brief remark. Is it possible that the above image has a linear approach after all, but instead in the CMYK space instead of RGB?

Comment: @phil13131 - Its interesting you ask that, as I am in the middle of making a version of this analysis program for the mac which will be able to function (i.e. pre-convert) to an color space prior to graphing, so that one can analyze in any color space. The goal is to also be able to setup approximation functions atop the graph, and generate code for the color SCALE in many differing languages.  If you have a mac, I would be more than willing to share :-)

Comment: I suspect the difference between linear interpolation and the curves shown in the graph are due to gamma correction.  Linear interpolation makes sense if your coordinate space is linear.  The actual algorithm here is probably to convert your sRGB (or gamma-corrected RGB) to linear RGB, compute the linear interpolation with those, and convert the interpolated values back to your non-linear display colorspace.

Answer (score 10):

A simple linear interpolation of the R,G,B values will do it.

[trumpetlicks has shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21835797/5987) that the image you used is not a pure linear interpolation. But I think an interpolation gives you the effect you're looking for. Below I show an image with a linear interpolation on top and your original image on the bottom.

[image: Top half linear interpolation, bottom half original]

And here's the (Python) code that produced it:

```
for y in range(height/2):
    for x in range(width):
        p = x / float(width - 1)
        r = int((1.0-p) * r1 + p * r2 + 0.5)
        g = int((1.0-p) * g1 + p * g2 + 0.5)
        b = int((1.0-p) * b1 + p * b2 + 0.5)
        pix[x,y] = (r,g,b)
```

Comment: Interesting - depends on what the OP is really looking for.  The original scale (image) does seem to provide higher contrast.

Comment: Not really on topic, but wouldn't it make more sense to do the y loop when the color is calculated for the given x? Equal amount of loops yet less calculating to do (I know, micro optimization for small images)

Comment: @engineercoding for a small example like this it really doesn't matter. And even when it does matter, it's not a simple decision - images are usually laid out with x in the lower order, making it more efficient to access the way my sample code shows. A modern processor can do a lot of calculations in the time it takes for a cache miss.

Comment: Can you please explain the code? what are `r1` , `r2` ..etc

Comment: @NullByte08 r1,g1,b1 are the RGB values of the left side and r2,g2,b2 are the RGB of the right. If you look up what "linear interpolation" means the rest should make sense.

Answer (score 6):

The HSV color space is not a very good color space to use for smooth transitions. This is because the `h` value, hue, is just used to arbitrarily define different colors around the 'color wheel'. That means if you go between two colors far apart on the wheel, you'll have to dip through a bunch of other colors. Not smooth at all.

It would make a lot more sense to use RGB (or CMYK). These 'component' color spaces are better defined to make smooth transitions because they represent how much of each 'component' a color needs.

A linear transition (see @trumpetlicks answer) for each component value, R, G and B should look 'pretty good'. Anything more than 'pretty good' is going to require an actual human to tweak the values because there are differences and asymmetries to how our eyes perceive color values in different color groups that aren't represented in either RBG or CMYK (or any standard).

The wikipedia image is using the algorithm that Photoshop uses. Unfortunately, that algorithm is not publicly available.

Comment: Hue is anything but arbitrary. Complementary colors have hues 180 degrees apart. the problem here is that the orange-to-blue transition is between complementary colors, 180 degrees apart, and a path which keeps SV constant (varying only H) produces half a rainbow.

Comment: @Msalters I understand, but while 'complementary' colors are well defined, their order around the color wheel is indeed arbitrary. There are many different ways that the wheel could be defined.

Comment: Well, that's not arbitrary either. The transformation from RGB space to HSV space is continuous; adjacent colors remain adjacent. That would not be the case if the hues were ordered arbitrarily.

Comment: @MSalters The RBG color space is three dimensional, which means that there are 6 'adjacent' colors for each color. The color wheel only selects two of those adjacent colors. There are many different way the color wheel could be set up that maintains the constraint that RGB to HSV is continuous. 'Arbitrary' might be too strong a word, but there is not just one ordering of colors that makes sense. There are many orders that would work. The traditional color wheel is just one of them.

Comment: @DamienBlack:  HSV is three-dimensional as well.  An arbitrary point in RGB has just as many neighbors as the corresponding point in HSV.

Comment: @MSalters - All of the work I have done (and I have written a program that allows someone to recreate (or create) the math for a color scale either from scratch or importing an image of a scale as reference) shows that someone can create the same scale using any color model with insignificant variance between results.  The graphs may look different, and thus the math that generates the actual output, but the image output is all but the same.

Comment: @trumpetlicks: That's mathematically fairly obvious. All 3D colorspaces try to describe the entire gamut of visible colors, with continuity in all color properties. That means a continuous path stays continuous under transformation. And because all colorspaces try to fairly divide the space over the different colors, those paths can't be compressed or stretched a lot. (Else you'd get the effect that the length of a path between two similar blue shades could differ a lot depending on the color space).

Answer (score 6):

I've been researching into this to build an [algorithm that takes a grayscale image as input and colorises it artificially](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/blob/master/qtSmoothColorTransition/main.cpp) according to a color palette:

**■■■■ Grayscale input ■■■■ Output ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■**

[image]
[image]

Just like many of the other solutions, the algorithm uses **linear interpolation** to make the transition between colours. With your example, `smooth_color_transition()` should be invoked with the following arguments:

```
QImage input("gradient.jpg");

QVector<QColor> colors;
colors.push_back(QColor(242, 177, 103)); // orange
colors.push_back(QColor(124, 162, 248)); // blue-ish

QImage output = smooth_color_transition(input, colors);    
output.save("output.jpg");
```

A comparison of the ***original image* VS *output*** from the algorithm can be seen below:

[image] *(output)*

[image] *(original)*

The visual artefacts that can be observed in the output are already present in the input (grayscale). The input image got these artefacts when it was resized to 189x51.

Here's another example that was created with a more complex color palette:

**■■■■ Grayscale input ■■■■ Output ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■**

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me like it would be easier to create the gradient using RGB values. You should first calculate the change in color for each value based on the width of the gradient. The following pseudocode would need to be done for R, G, and B values.

```
redDifference = (redValue2 - redValue1) / widthOfGradient
```

You can then render each pixel with these values like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < widthOfGradient; i++) {
    int r = round(redValue1 + i * redDifference)
    // ...repeat for green and blue

    drawLine(i, r, g, b)
}
```

I know you specified that you're using C++, but I created a JSFiddle demonstrating this working with your first gradient as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/eumf7/